# Proper CNAME for web configuration

Tags: dns, web-hosting, cname

I'm trying to configure website to be hosted on Google Cloud Platform. After adding CNAME record below addresses work:

```
www.spinaczagencja.pl
spinaczagencja.pl
http://www.spinaczagencja.pl
```

but this one doesn't work:

```
http://spinaczagencja.pl
```

Here is CNAME DNS record added to domain:
[image]

Do you have any ideas what can I do to make it work with "http://spinaczagencja.pl"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another entry in your DNS pointing the naked domain to Alias.

```
@     www
```